# I have a gooseneck vent on my roof connected to nothing. Im told the purpose of the gooseneck is for attic exhaust ventilation. Is that correct?

Tags: attic, ventilation

Condominium development. ALL or most a/C units cannot keep 1220 square ft cool. I believe it is due to the only exhaust vent for attic is the current gooseneck vent that is sitting on the roof. Going into attic, the gooseneck is connected to nothing. Is that a good or bad situation. I do, however,  gave multiple soffit vents front and back of condo for intake.

Comment: A gooseneck vent is one way to vent attic space. Depending on the square footage there should be multiple vents.  The AC issues can be caused by a number of things.

Comment: More likely the root problem is due to abysmal insulation and windows, in my experience of the sort of people that build condos, who never intend to live in one themselves. The area of the attic and the size of the vent would be needed to know if it's adequate or inadequate. If the attic can have additional insulation installed (be sure to use baffles to keep the soffit vents clear) that's likely the first/best/cheapest/most-effective thing to do.